# How to inherit vanilla option component in a custom option component in react-select v2?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I want to put some custom option stuff but keep using the native component inside.

The idea is just to inherit, specialize, without full rewriting of the rendering.

With the V1 this code was well working , for my custom option component :

```
import React from 'react';
import components from "react-select";
class MyCustomOption extends React.Component {
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
    }
    render()
    {
        return <div title={this.props.title}><components.Option {...this.props} /></div> }
    }
}
```

with the v2 I can't manage to make this code works : I have the following error when rendering the custom option
:

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string
>   (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your
>   component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up
>   default and named imports.

Answer (score 2):

In `react-select` the `components` import needs to be done the following way:

```
import { components } from "react-select";
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, it was not the only problem but it was the main blocking step

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Laura. Here is the corrected code :

```
import React from 'react';
import {components} from "react-select";
class MyCustomOption extends React.Component {
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
    }
    render()
    {
        return <div title={this.props.data.title}><components.Option {...this.props} /></div> }
    }
}
```